# How do I unit test a class that has private methods and fields using xUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

I'm trying to unit test class methods with private access modifier and it is not possible to modify accessibility of these methods.

```cs
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // business code
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MyMethod);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will not test them from unit test. You will test them through testing of public methods and properties.

Comment: @Fabio I got no public methods, I've only private methods and they have business logic that I need to run tests on it.

Comment: How does it work? If your class has no public interface, how can that logic execute at all?

Comment: It absolutely has a public interface but just a method calls.
something like this: `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MyMethod);` and MyMehod() is private.
@dymanoid

Comment: Please show your class or example how you going to use it in your application. When you write tests you will write code which will use your class under test. So for answering your question we need to see how you going to use it

Comment: I've updated my post to include code example.kindly check it.@Fabio

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't put business code into the presentation/UI layer
2. If you still have code in your UI layer that is worthwhile to test, use Model/View/Presenter or Model/View/Controller or even [Humble View](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#HumbleView) to separate that code from the actual UI classes and make them testable this way.

Note bene: Your class does have public methods. They are hidden away in its parent class.

Answer (score -3):

You can make temporary internal methods for testing:

```
internal void MyMethodForTest(object sender, EventArgs e) //test method
{
    //business code
}

private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) //real method
{
    //business code
}
```

Then, add this line so the test can access your internal method:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTest")]
```

After you are done testing, you can then delete the internal test method.